# how can I deal with throttling?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, fios

I have Verizon FiOS and it seems as if certain things will cause the connection to slow down greatly. if there are a few people on skype, the internet speed drops greatly for the rest of the day even if they are no longer connected and using skype.
this causes youtube videos and webpages to load slowly. I recently discovered some games cause this to happen as well, WarThunder(and possible world-of-tanks) causes this to happen for the computer involved with downloading the game(doesn't seem to effect the other PC's like skype does). I think it has something to do with the P2P torrent system built in, and/or streaming services, but I'm not sure how I should deal with this issue. it persists even after disconnecting, so it doesn't seem to be a bandwidth issue with any particular computer on the network.
I'm using a home network, so it doesn't make sense to cut the speed of a paid connection.

Comment: If Verizon chooses to throttle your connection there are not a great deal of options, you could use a VPN, but given your potential connection speed you might see a huge decrease ( you want get the maximum potential out of your connection ).

Comment: I see. I've tried a couple other providers in the past but they delivered slow internet browsing. this one provides decent browsing for simple pages but I find it disappointing that I can't download what I need to with it.

Comment: Your inability to use torrent software isn't Verizon's concern.  If you are being throttle with other P2P traffic thats entirely different matter.  A VPN would prevent the throttling at least.